# Sort the contents of the textfile in ascending

Tags: php, sorting

I am trying to develop a code that will sort the contents of the text file in ascending order. I have read the contents of the file and was able to display the texts. 
I am having difficulty sorting them out in from low to high order, word by word.

I have tried the asort from php.net, but just could not get the code to work well. 
thanks.

Comment: Please post some code, when you read the file do you do it line per line? Could you give us some lines of your text file as example.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. I have a change of question though i don't know if it is allowed here. I have a text file, and has one paragraph. see first paragraph of 'Lorem Ipsum'. I want to display the words line by line. how do i do that?

Comment: like splitting them one by one. separated by line breaks.

Comment: Read whole text, then `explode` it into array and simply `foreach` them all! Or `str_replace` whitespaces into `<br />`

Comment: thanks. i'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second question, you can read the text file into into a variable (like you've said you have already), eg. $variable, then use explode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to separate, at each space, each word into an array:

```
//$variable is the content from your text file
$output = explode(" ",$variable); //explode the content at each space

//loop through the resulting array and output
for ($counter=0; $counter < count($output); $counter++) {

   echo $output[$counter] . "<br/>"; //output screen with a line break after each

} //end for loop
```

If your paragraph contains commas etc which you don't want to output you can replace those in the variable before exploding it.

Comment: thanks. i have a working code now but i am not really sure about it. would it be OK for you guys to take a look at it?

Comment: By all means post your code - it helps us answer anyway ;) Have you managed to sort this out because you haven't chosen an answer yet??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$filecontent = file_get_contents('exemple.txt');

$words = preg_split('/[\s,.;":!()?\'\-\[\]]+/', $filecontent, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$array_lowercase = array_map('strtolower', $words);

array_multisort($array_lowercase, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $words);


foreach($words as $value)
{
    echo "$value <br>";

}

?>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, please post stuff like this as a comment :)

Comment: Thank you, i added it as comment, and i've posted a real answer.

Comment: hi, thanks for taking time. i finally got it. but i am not really sure if what i did is correct.

Comment: @freeloader : Then post what you did so as we can see it, you can try my code it is working i tested it for you.

Comment: @Imane Fateh: this may sound really dumb but where do i post it so all of you guys can see?

Comment: Under you question you can click edit and add it, or post it as answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Split file by newlines "\n" into an array using explode()
$file = explode("\n",file_get_contents('foo.txt'));
//sort array with sort()
sort($file);
//Build string and display sorted contents.
echo implode("\n<br />",$file);
```

Sort functions needs to have an array as argument, make sure your file is in an array. `asort` is for associative arrays, so unless you need to keep the array keys you can use `sort` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "Hello world\ngoodbye.";

$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $file);
$clean_words = preg_replace("/[[:punct:]]+/", "", $words);

foreach ($clean_words as $key => $val) {
    echo "words[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

--output:--
words[0] = Hello
words[1] = world
words[2] = goodbye



sort($clean_words,  SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);

foreach ($clean_words as $key => $val) {
    echo "words[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

--output:--
words[0] = goodbye
words[1] = Hello
words[2] = world
```

Comment: thanks. i will try this one, but can you take a look at the code that i have. thanks again